# Probability of succes when painting hexagon with different colours

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We pain each side and diagonal of a regular hexagon with one of three colours white, black and red (colours for different line segments we choose independently from one another). Let x denote number of triangles painted with one colour only  and with vertices at the same position as vertices of a hexagon. Find $\mathbb{E}X$.
My question is not about general thing, but rather about a fact why the probability of success is equal to $1/9$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a particular of these triangles. There are  $3^3=27$ equiprobable ways its edges can be colored, and  exactly three of these colorings are uniform. It follows that the probability of success for this triangle is ${1\over9}$. Since there are ${6\choose 3}=20$ triangles in all the expected number $E(X)$ of uniformly colored triangles is ${20\over9}$.